# error j2ee using eclipse wildfly

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly-8

```
  oct. 30, 2015 5:51:05 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>            INFO: XNIO version 3.3.0.Beta2
   oct. 30, 2015 5:51:05 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
   INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.0.Beta2
   oct. 30, 2015 5:51:06 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
  INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.5.Beta1
  javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to any server.Servers tried: [http-remoting://localhost:9990 (java.io.IOException: Unknown service name)]
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.failOverSequence(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:244)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingStore(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:149)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingOperation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:130)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.lookup(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:272)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:87)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:129)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
at tn.esprit.client.TestCalculator.main(TestCalculator.java:18)
```

can anyone help me please :) ?
i'm using wildfly and eclipse 
if you're looking for more informations please ask me thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue with Infinispan jmx configuration.

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
        <expose-resolved-model/>
        <expose-expression-model/>
        <remoting-connector use-management-endpoint="false"/>
    </subsystem>
```

After I removed the `use-management-endpoint="false"` I was able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong port, 9990 is the management console port